# Input only for float values

Tags: jquery

I have an `input` element with the class `numbersOnly` which only should allow to write (with keyboard) this numberformat -> `#,##` eg. `2,04` or `39,14`

Also when 2 digits are before the comma the first digit is not allowed to be **0**.

I am testing with this code - but I still have no luck.

```
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^[0-9]*[,][0-9]+$/,'');
});
```

Comment: Should probably return false with the function when an invalid key comes in, rather than attempting to make it empty.  No need to do the assignment manually, just filter key strokes.

Comment: So would "2,23" be a valid string? Or it has to be 2 digits? What do you want to happen when a user types in "02,33"?

Comment: @PherricOxide the user shouldn't be able to write "02,33" -> it should be change to "2,33" - but the number would be "2,04" there should be the "0" before "4"

Comment: The "2,04" is hard, because when the user types "2,4", you don't know if they're going to keep typing another number or not. You'd have to either change the string when they leave the input field, or just reformat the string when you're reading/processing it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [jQuery Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

Might be a simpler way, but this seems to work. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8GU6e/4/

This does assume any number of digits is valid, I wasn't entirely clear you wanted that. Is "12,12345" valid? This assumes it is. Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

```
$('.numbersOnly').keypress(function (e) { 
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    // Firefox will trigger this even on nonprintabel chars... allow them.
    switch (charCode) {
        case 8: // Backspace
        case 0: // Arrow keys, delete, etc
            return true;
        default:
    }

    var lastChar =  String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    // Reject anything not numbers or a comma
    if (!lastChar.match("[0-9]|,")) {return false;}

    // Reject comma if 1st character or if we already have one
    if (lastChar == "," && this.value.length == 0) {return false;}
    if (lastChar == "," && this.value.indexOf(",") != -1) {return false;}

    // Cut off first char if 0 and we have a comma somewhere
    if (this.value.indexOf(",") != -1 && this.value[0] == "0") {
        this.value = this.value.substr(1);
    }

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Updated with a version that works on both Chrome and Firefox.